# Form text displaying vertically in Explorer?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a small single page site, and I have a part of my form showing text vertically instead of horizontally in explorer - "vehicle condition" Any idea what I'm doing wrong? My site is here - http://yourtradein.ca/ Code is listed below.

```
 <div class="wdform-page-and-images" style="display:table; border-top:0px solid black;">
 <div id="form_id_tempform_view1" class="wdform_page" page_title="Untitled page" next_title="Next" next_type="text" next_class="wdform-page-button" next_checkable="false" previous_title="Previous" previous_type="text" previous_class="wdform-page-button" previous_checkable="false">
      <div class="wdform_section">
           <div class="wdform_column">
                <div wdid="1" class="wdform_row">
                     %1 - Name:%
                </div>
                <div wdid="2" class="wdform_row">
                     %2 - Phone:%
                </div>
                <div wdid="3" class="wdform_row">
                     %3 - E-mail:%
                </div>
                <div wdid="11" class="wdform_row">
                     %11 - Vehicle Description: %
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="wdform_column">
                <div wdid="6" class="wdform_row">
                     %6 - Vehicle Year:%
                </div>
                <div wdid="5" class="wdform_row">
                     %5 - Vehicle Make:%
                </div>
                <div wdid="12" class="wdform_row">
                     %12 - Vehicle Model:%
                </div>
                <div wdid="14" class="wdform_row">
                     %14 - Vehicle Mileage:%
                </div>
                <div wdid="15" class="wdform_row">
                     %15 - VIN Number:%
                </div>
                <div wdid="8" class="wdform_row">
                     %8 - Trim Package:%
                </div>
                <div wdid="9" class="wdform_row">
                     %9 - Vehicle Options:%
                </div>
                <div wdid="10" class="wdform_row">
                     %10 - Vehicle Condition:%
                </div>
                <div wdid="13" class="wdform_row">
                     %13 - type_submit_reset_13%
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
      <div valign="top" class="wdform_footer" style="width: 100%;">
           <div style="width: 100%;">
                <div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
                     <div style="display: table-row-group;">
                          <div id="form_id_temppage_nav1" style="display: table-row;">
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: weird - looks fine in my IE (11.0.96)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any issues in explorer or chrome. Could you please be more descriptive of the problem? the vehicle condition is showing horizontal just like you say you desire. Maybe update your Internet Explorer.